# Does a Magento update overwrite changes in the js folder?

Tags: magento, tinymce, upgrade

I have made some changes to the setup.js settings file that is in the /js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce directory.
Will these changes get lost after an upgrade? Is there a way to duplicate this folder like when creating a frontend theme?

Thanks

Comment: Yep, /app, /lib, /js, /skin will all see their key files being overwritten in an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You can add your custom folder inside JS folder, create your own js and paste Below code , it is overwrite js function, and call it where you need

```
if (typeof tinyMceWysiwygSetup != 'undefined') {
  tinyMceWysiwygSetup.addMethods({
      //here is example for you, suppose if you have changed something in below function
      initialize: function(htmlId, config)
    {
        this.id = htmlId;
        this.config = config;
        varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('tinymceChange', this.onChangeContent.bind(this));
        this.notifyFirebug();
        if(typeof tinyMceEditors == 'undefined') {
            tinyMceEditors = $H({});
        }
        tinyMceEditors.set(this.id, this);

        // Paste here your custom code
    }
  });
}
```

May be this help for you.